# C++ Accessing operator function in inherited class

Tags: c++, inheritance, eigen

I am currently writing an application where I use the Eigen-Library for complex 3D-Math. Because I needed distinct point and vector classes, my point3d-class looks like this:

```
class point3d : public Eigen::Vector4d
{
public:
    point3d(){}
    point3d(double x, double y, double z) : Eigen::Vector4d(x, y, z, 1) {}
    void fromString(std::string input);
};
```

Now I want to create a member function of this class that allows me to parse lines of OBJ-files which look like this:

```
v 2.8 0.52 10.18
```

as such point. This is how I intend to design my parsing function

```
void point3d::fromString(std::string input)
{
    char* buf = strdup(input.c_str());
    if (strtok(buf, " ") == "v")
    {

        ;
        strtok(buf, " ");
        this-x = std::stod(strtok(buf, " "));
        this->y = std::stod(strtok(buf, " "));
        this->z = std::stod(strtok(buf, " "));  

    }
}
```

My problem is that Eigen does not allow me to access the data stored in Vector4d as this->x, this-y, this->z and so on. Instead, you'd usually access it as Vector4d v; v[0], v[1], v[2] etc. I think the way it does that is by using a

```
double Eigen::Vector4d::operator[](unsigned int index){...}
```

function.

I don't know how exactly one would access that data in a derived class. What do I have to do to access this data within that function so that I can write to the x, y, z values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
(*this)[0]
```

and so on in order to call the base class `operator[]`.

Answer (score 1):

`x`, `y`, `z` aren't member variables of `Eigen::Vector4d`, but methods. You can access them from your derived class using `this->x()` etc (or `Vector4d::x()`). What also works is `(*this)[0]` or `(*this)(0)`. If you need to access `x()`, `y()`, `z()` frequently in your class, you  could write once:

```
using Vector4d::x;
using Vector4d::y;
using Vector4d::z;
```

And afterwards access them using just `x()`, `y()`, `z()`. However, this may cause some shadowing conflicts (if you name local variables the same way).

Comment: Ahh, I see. Well, this is what happens if one is too lazy to actually inspect an imported library before using it. Thanks for your answer.